# XCode 4.3 and SVN

Tags: xcode, svn, repository

I'm new to iOS developing, I haven't used earlier versions of XCode.

Yet I have stored my project on my local hd. Now I want to use some online subversion service.

I cannot seem to find the appropriate options in XCode. The hints that I googled all refer to a menu called SCM which I don't seem to have.

I created a new and empty repository online (webbased) and tried to configure XCode to use it by selecting the "Connect to a repository" menu when xcode starts. After some tweeking in the command line this "connect to a repository" succeeded but afterwards XCode simply closed itself again.

I tried copying the files that belong to my project to the path that I set up to be used with SVN manually. I opened the project in XCode from that path and after adding another file wanted to commit that change but couldn't find how to do that from within XCode.

Now I found that in XCode / Organizer / Repositories / MyProject is listed but has the type "GIT", which is wrong.

Do I have to change the repository type to SVN instead of GIT? If so, how can I?

Answer (score 0):

When you created the project there was an option to put the project under source control. This option creates a git repository and is checked by default.

To use SVN you have to import your project into the SVN repository. (And you probably don't want it to be under git and svn at the same time, so you'll either delete the .git folder or recreate your project without the scm option selected.) Once the project is imported into your repository then you make sure Xcode knows about the repository and you can check the project out.

---

But really I'd recommend just using Git. It's a modern version control system with lots of nice features (though to do much of anything out of the ordinary requires using the command line) and there are nice project hosting sites for it like [GitHub](http://github.com). I don't think SVN compares very well to git.